# can file be named with today's date in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am doing soapui testing, wherein i want to save request & response suffixed with todaydate.

here's my code:

```
// Create a File object representing the folder 'A/B'
def folder = new File( 'C:/Project/SOAPUI' )
// If it doesn't exist
if( !folder.exists() ) {
// Create all folders up-to and including B
folder.mkdirs() 
}

def myOutFile = "C:/Project/SOAPUI/test_request.txt"
def request = context.expand( '${test#Request}' )

def f = new File(myOutFile)
f.write(request, "UTF-8")
```

=====================

I want the file name to be test_request(+today's date)

Can you suggest me some options?

Comment: So, what's the problem exactly? Getting today's date (`new Date()`)? format it to a String (use `SimpleDateFormat`)? Concatenate two strings (`String c = a + b;`)? This is all googleable.

Comment: @JBNizet I would not recommend using `SimpleDateFormat` and I would not recommend using the `+` operator to concatenate the strings here.  I think the question is a reasonable question and I think the answer that @emmanuel-rosa provided is reasonable as well.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option:

```
def myOutFile = "C:/Project/SOAPUI/test_request_${(new Date()).format('yyyy-MM-dd')}.txt"
```

The output looks like *C:/Project/SOAPUI/test_request_2015-08-30.txt*